Include clickable 'Fig.'/'Table' in \ref without duplication in captions
I want references to include 'Fig.'/'Table' before the number so they are clickable and in link color. In the captions, remove 'Figure'/'Table' to avoid duplication like 'Figure Fig. 1'/'Table Table 1'.
The code below partly achieves this but leaves a space before the caption text. 'Fig. 1'/'Table 1' should be perfectly aligned with the remainder of the caption. Hard-coding \hspace{-.35em} from eyeballing to fix this is unsatisfactory and also inconsistent in longer documents, as the needed \hspace obviously varies.
How can I ensure 'Fig.'/'Table' are included in \ref as clickable links and avoid duplication in captions without adding extra space?
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=blue, linkcolor=blue, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{labelfont={bf}, justification=raggedright, singlelinecheck=false}
\newcommand{\mylipsum}{Lorem
ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum
ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.}

% Redefine \thefigure to include "Fig."
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{Fig.~\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{Table~\arabic{table}}

% Redefine \figurename to be empty, so it doesn't add "Figure"
\renewcommand{\figurename}{}
\renewcommand{\tablename}{}

% \renewcommand{\figurename}{\hspace{-.35em}}
% \renewcommand{\tablename}{\hspace{-.35em}}

\begin{document}

Figure \ref{fig:example} and Table \ref{tab:example} are referenced within this text. \mylipsum

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image} 
    \caption{\textbf{An example figure.} \mylipsum}
    \label{fig:example}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
        \toprule
        Column 1 & Column 2 \\
        \midrule
        Data 1   & Data 2   \\
        Data 3   & Data 4   \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{\textbf{An example table.} \mylipsum}
    \label{tab:example}
\end{table}

\end{document}



Are you sure you want Figure \ref{fig:example} and Table \ref{tab:example}, or would you rather have \ref{fig:example} and \ref{tab:example} are? Please advise.

@Mico The example text was a bit unfortunate, but fortunately you understood it right.


I want [cross-]references to include 'Fig.'/'Table' before the number so they are clickable and in link color.

In addition to employing the hyperref package (which you do already), you only need to (a) load the cleveref package with options nameinlink and capitalize and (b) employ the package's \cref user macro instead of \ref. Observe that \cref can take more than one argument. In particular,
\cref{fig:example,tab:example}

produces "Fig. 1 and Table 1" with the required coloring, as stipulated according to your posting.

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%% Note that I've reduced the code to the bare minimum.
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalize,nameinlink]{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\cref{fig:example,tab:example} are cross-referenced within this text.

% create two invisible floats that can nevertheless be cross-referenced
\begin{figure}
\refstepcounter{figure}\label{fig:example}
\end{figure}
\begin{table}
\refstepcounter{table}\label{tab:example}
\end{table}

\end{document}


I thougth of it, but it doesn't work for multiple references. If you test your solution with 2 tables, for instance, you'll get "Table 1 and 2" and not "Table 1 and Table 2" as requested ("I want references to include 'Fig.'/'Table' before the number so they are clickable").

@NBur - Actually, the approach outlined in my answer would produce "Tables 1 and 2, not "Table 1 and 2", with the substrings "Tables 1" and "2" made into hypertargets.

Sorry for the typo. But there is no "Table" in front of "2".

@NBur - The OP specified "Fig. 1 and Table 1" as the desired output for a case that involves two separate types of objects to be cross-referenced. Unless I'm badly mistaken, nowhere did they express a preference for how a cross-reference to two objects of the same type should be formatted. In particular, I can't find a claim that a cross-reference of the form "Table 1 and Table 2" is to be preferred to "Tables 1 and 2".

Maybe you can use the cleveref package.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=blue, linkcolor=blue, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefformat{figure}{#2Fig.~#1#3}
\crefrangeformat{figure}{#3Fig.~#1#4 to~#5Fig.~#2#6}
\crefmultiformat{figure}{#2Fig.~#1#3}{ and~#2Fig.~#1#3}{, #2Fig.~#1#3}{ and~#2Fig.~#1#3}
\crefrangemultiformat{figure}{#2Fig.~#1#3}{ and~#2Fig.~#1#3}{, #2Fig.~#1#3}{ and~#2Fig.~#1#3}
\crefformat{table}{#2Tab.~#1#3}
\crefrangeformat{table}{#3Tab.~#1#4 to~#5Tab.~#2#6}
\crefmultiformat{table}{#2Tab.~#1#3}{ and~#2Tab.~#1#3}{, #2Tab.~#1#3}{ and~#2Tab.~#1#3}
\crefrangemultiformat{table}{#2Tab.~#1#3}{ and~#2Tab.~#1#3}{, #2Tab.~#1#3}{ and~#2Tab.~#1#3}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{labelfont={bf}, justification=raggedright, singlelinecheck=false}
\newcommand{\mylipsum}{Lorem
  ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum
  ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.}

% \renewcommand{\figurename}{\hspace{-.35em}}
% \renewcommand{\tablename}{\hspace{-.35em}}

\begin{document}
  
  Figure \cref{fig:example} and Tables \cref{tab:example,tab:example2} are referenced within this text. \mylipsum
  
  \begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image} 
    \caption{\textbf{An example figure.} \mylipsum}
    \label{fig:example}
  \end{figure}
  
  \begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
      \toprule
      Column 1 & Column 2 \\
      \midrule
      Data 1   & Data 2   \\
      Data 3   & Data 4   \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{\textbf{An example table.} \mylipsum}
    \label{tab:example}
  \end{table}
  
  \begin{table}[h!]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    \toprule
    Column 1 & Column 2 \\
    \midrule
    Data 1   & Data 2   \\
    Data 3   & Data 4   \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{\textbf{An example table.} \mylipsum}
  \label{tab:example2}
  \end{table}
  
\end{document}


